# Loop through first 3 instances

Tags: jquery

How can I loop through the first three instances of '.slide-item img' within a document?

```
var set = [];
$('.slide-item img').each(function() {
    var img = $(this).data('src');
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(this).remove();
    set.push([img,id]); 
});
```

The above loops through all, but I am not sure how to limit it.

Comment: Have you looked at jquery's [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function? They explain how to use the function callback passed into $.each :)

Comment: there are really too many ways to do this.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limit your selection to begin with:

```
$(".slide-item img:lt(3)");
```

Read more: [`:lt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

```
$('.slide-item img').slice(0, 3).each(function() {
  //...
```